# PHP loop through an array to grab specific values

Tags: php, loops

Wondering how to grab the following values from this array: campaignID, campaign, impressions, clicks, and cost. For example, I would like to get the following results:

campaignID - 9039077962 campaign: CG - Smart Shopping - USA impressions - 1951940 clicks - 10726 cost - 5324010696

I've started with a forloop but am unable to get any value back I'm just getting: ArrayArrayArray

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    echo $array[2]['row'][$i]['@attributes']['campaignID'];
}
```

This is my array and it's printed results:

```
    $array = simplexml_load_string($reportDownloadResult->getAsString());
 

     print_r( $result );
        
    RESULTS------------------------------------------->
    
       Array
    (
        [report-name] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
                )

        )

    [date-range] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Jul 13, 2020-Jul 19, 2020
                )

        )

    [table] => Array
        (
            [columns] => Array
                (
                    [column] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => campaignID
                                            [display] => Campaign ID
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => campaign
                                            [display] => Campaign
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => A

rray
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => impressions
                                                [display] => Impressions
                                            )
    
                                    )
    
                                [3] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => clicks
                                                [display] => Clicks
                                            )
    
                                    )
    
                                [4] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => cost
                                                [display] => Cost
                                            )
    
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                    )
    
                [row] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 9039077962
                                        [campaign] => CG - Smart Shopping - USA
                                        [impressions] => 1951940
                                        [clicks] => 10726
                                        [cost] => 5324010696
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 9040836852
                                        [campaign] => CG - RLSA - USA
                                        [impressions] => 58
                                        [clicks] => 9
                                        [cost] => 3830000
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 9335113576
                                        [campaign] => CG - Youtube - Remarketing - US
                                        [impressions] => 11727
                                        [clicks] => 45
                                        [cost] => 470305195
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 9336396427
                                        [campaign] => CG - Gmail Display Remarketing - USA
                                        [impressions] => 197
                                        [clicks] => 29
                                        [cost] => 3581214
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 9503218446
                                        [campaign] => CG - Shopping - USA - Remarketing
                                        [impressions] => 1169
                                        [clicks] => 13
                                        [cost] => 26480000
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 9507461506
                                        [campaign] => CG - Non-branded - Subscription - USA
                                        [impressions] => 6681
                                        [clicks] => 344
                                        [cost] => 813030000
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 9599121241
                                        [campaign] => CG - Display - Remarketing - USA
                                        [impressions] => 13930
                                        [clicks] => 156
                                        [cost] => 21271733
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [7] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 10381122443
                                        [campaign] => CG - Branded - USA - Relaunch
                                        [impressions] => 4436
                                        [clicks] => 1113
                                        [cost] => 252800000
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [8] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 10438544600
                                        [campaign] => CG - Non-branded Dynamic Shop - USA
                                        [impressions] => 75
                                        [clicks] => 13
                                        [cost] => 13430000
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [9] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 10494687070
                                        [campaign] => CG - Non-branded - Shop - USA
                                        [impressions] => 107
                                        [clicks] => 8
                                        [cost] => 11890000
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [10] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 10503251956
                                        [campaign] => CG - Gmail Display Remarketing - USA - Box Themes
                                        [impressions] => 13490
                                        [clicks] => 1050
                                        [cost] => 525795143
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                        [11] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [campaignID] => 10505435235
                                        [campaign] => CG - Non-branded - Subscription - CANADA
                                        [impressions] => 1350
                                        [clicks] => 91
                                        [cost] => 131890000
                                    )
    
                            )
    
                    )
    
            )
    
    )
```

Comment: As you are working with XML, it would be easier to show the original XML rather than the converted array.

Comment: Yes, I'm working with XML, but I need to insert each value into a db, so I figured looping through an array would be best. Open to suggestions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use Simple XML's methods to navigate through the data, rather than treating it as arrays. But if you really have to, I'll show it below.

I generally recommend using `foreach` rather than `for` to loop over arrays. But if you're going to use a `for` loop with array indexes, they should be based on the `count()` of the same array you're indexing into. It doesn't make sense to use `count($array)` and then use that to index into `$array[2]['row']` -- you should use `count($array[2]['row'])`.

I'm not sure where you're getting `$array[2]` from in your code. The top-level array doesn't have any numbered indexes, it's an associative array. Numbered indexes aren't used until you get to the `row` and `column` elements nested deep within.

```
foreach ($result['table']['row'] as $row) {
    $attrs = $row['@attributes'];
    echo $attrs['campaignID'];
    echo $attrs['campaign'];
    echo $attrs['impressions'];
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: This was so helpful. Thank you very much! What would you suggest to get the same results using Simple XML methods?

Comment: Read the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: DOM has more features: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach ($result['table']['row'] as $row) {
    $compaign = $row['@attributes'];
    echo  $compaign['campaignID'].', '.$compaign['campaign'].', '.$compaign['impressions'].', '.$compaign['clicks'].', '.$compaign['cost'].' <br />';
}

#This would print all the compaign as single compaign per row
```